# How to swith email boxes from qmail to courrier?

Tags: email

sorry if I'm not precise enough, but I'm not an admin sys, but I will maybe need to transfer email account from qmail to courrier, isn it possible ?
I don't even know if "courrier" is a really existing mail program ?

Thx!

Comment: Yes, Courier IMAP/POP are a way of picking up mail. The most common format for storing Mail is using the "Maildir" format which has "cur", "new" and "tmp" sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

I did this quite a while ago. IIRC there's a couple of ways of doing it. I think `mb2md` is best.

Details can be found [here](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/mb2md/).